# Dar espaçamentos entre textos e campos de preenchimento

Tags: html, css

Quero ter um espaçamento entre alguns texto/campos de preenchimento um do outro, exemplo:

Razão Social:ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤContato:

[CAMPO DE PREENCHIMENTO]ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ[CAMPO DE PREENCHIMENTO]

Se conseguirem dar uma dicas pra deixar a programação mais limpa estou aceitando sou novo nessa área. Valeu!

```html
<body>
    <form id="contato" onsubmit="submitForm()">
        <p><span style="color: #00347e; font-size: 14px;">PROPOSTA TÉCNICA COMERCIAL</span></p>
        <input name="size" type="radio" value="PROPOSTA TÉCNICA COMERCIAL | GABIÕES" />GABIÕES<br />
        <input name="size" type="radio" value="PROPOSTA TÉCNICA COMERCIAL | GEODRENOS" />GEODRENOS<br />
        <input name="size" type="radio" value="PROPOSTA TÉCNICA COMERCIAL | TELAS SOLDADAS" />TELAS SOLDADAS<br />
        <p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">Razão Social</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="Razao-Social" size="10" type="text" value=" " /></p>
        <p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">CNPJ|CPF</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="CNPJ|CPF" size="10" type="text" value=" " /></p>
        <p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">Endereço da Obra</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="Cidade-UF" size="10" type="text" value=" " /></p>
        <p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">Contato</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="Contato" size="10" type="text" value=" " /><br />
        <p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">Telefone</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="Telefone" size="10" type="text" value=" " /><br />
        <p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">E-mail</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="E-mail" size="10" type="text" value=" " /><br />    
            <br><p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">Produtos</span></p>
            <select Name="Name_of_list_box" Size="Number_of_options">  
            <option> Zn/Al </option>  
            <option> Zn/Al + PVC </option>  
            <option> Geodreno </option>
            </br></select>

            <br><p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">Malha</span></p>
            <select Name="Name_of_list_box" Size="Number_of_options">  
            <option> Zn/Al 8x10 </option>  
            <option> PVC 8x10 </option>  
            <option> PVC 6x8 </option>
        </br></select>  


            <br><p><span style="color: #e47610; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;">Unidade</span></p>
            <select Name="Name_of_list_box" Size="Number_of_options">  
            <option> pç </option>  
            <option> m³ </option>  
            </br></select>
    </form>
</body>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloque cada bloco de texto+input num elemento `<div>` por exemplo e adicione propriedades como `display: flex`, etc... e remova esse monte de css dentro dos elementos, coloque a formação em classs `css`, especialmente o que está duplicado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria algo assim:
HTML

```
<div class='div-esquerda'>
<input type='text' ></input>
<div class='div-direita'><input type='text' ></input></div>
```

CSS

```
.div-direita{
margin-left:3em;} //medida que você quer
```

PS: sugestão seu CSS nos elementos são repetidos, logo você pode criar uma CLASS para eles que são repetidos e fazer como coloquei acima, porém com as medidas diferentes.